# jQuery slowing down the fade animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm using [pagify.js](https://github.com/cmpolis/Pagify) for a one page site. As a default there is an instant fade out / fade in when I click to a different page, here's the code:

```
$('#page_holder').pagify({
      pages: ['about', 'directory', 'archive','contribute'],
      animationOut: 'fadeOut',
      animationOutSpeed: '100',
      animation: 'fadeIn',
      animationSpeed: '100',
      'default': 'about',
      cache: true 
    });
```

This is great but it's too fast, ideally when I click to a different page I want the both the `fadeOut` / `fadeIn` to be executed at much slower speeds.

I've tried to apply `fast`, `slow` as well as various milliseconds to the animations but nothing seems to be changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagify.js uses jQuery's own animation functions. jQuery uses actual numbers for it's animate duration values. The only string values allowed are `'fast'` and `'slow'`, and these will be used to look up actual predefined numbers. Any other string will result in a default value being used. Technically `"_default"` could be used as well, but no sense in actually using it since it will default to that anyway.

So since you are passing in the string version of 100: `"100"`, jQuery is going to end up doing the following (relevant code snippets below)

1. `if( typeof "100" !== "number" )`

   true, because it's "string"
2. `if( "100" in jQuery.fx.speeds )`

   false, speeds only holds fast, slow, and _default
3. `opt.duration = jQuery.fx.speeds._default;`

   set the default duration.

**Fix:** use actual numbers instead of string versions of them.

---

**jQuery's predefined speeds**

> https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/731c501155ef139f53029c0e58409b80f0af3a0c/src/effects.js#L691
>
> ```
> jQuery.fx.speeds = {
>   slow: 600,
>   fast: 200,
>
>   // Default speed
>   _default: 400
> };
> ```

**jQuery's animate function**

calls the speed() function to get the proper settings/methods to be used.

> https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/731c501155ef139f53029c0e58409b80f0af3a0c/src/effects.js#L514
>
> ```
> animate: function( prop, speed, easing, callback ) {
>   var empty = jQuery.isEmptyObject( prop ),
>       optall = jQuery.speed( speed, easing, callback ),
> ```

**speed() function**

determining the correct duration to use

> https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/731c501155ef139f53029c0e58409b80f0af3a0c/src/effects.js#L472
>
> ```
> if ( typeof opt.duration !== "number" ) {
>   if ( opt.duration in jQuery.fx.speeds ) {
>       opt.duration = jQuery.fx.speeds[ opt.duration ];
>
>   } else {
>       opt.duration = jQuery.fx.speeds._default;
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting animationSpeed to a number instead of a string? Like `100` instead of `'100'`

Comment: Thanks, worked well...How can I add a 'delay' in between the 'fadeOut' and 'fadeIn'?

Comment: A cursory glance at the docs suggests this is not currently possible. You can file an issue here though: https://github.com/cmpolis/Pagify